# Xamarin forms: custom view as a cell

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cell

In my project, I need to create a list of feeds, something like:

[image]

I think to create a XAML content view, but how can use it as a cell?

Is it a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to go is to choose Data Template Selector. If you use Data Template Selector, You can Choose a DataTemplate (view) at runtime based on the value of a data-bound property. Lets say, In your case, your List view might have 3/4 or any number of different kind of ViewCell. Based on the type of cell you want to display different view cell.

There is a nice tutorial on Xamarin doc, you can read at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Read this one after that (this is a example for Chat App using ViewCell) https://blog.xamarin.com/customizing-list-view-cells-xamarin-forms-datatemplateselector/

Let me know if you need any specific help after reading that.

Comment: Tx . My cell is the same , I update the image. Still  data template is necesary for that?

Comment: Your listview renders the bound data using a data template. You do not need a data template selector if you only have one template you want to use. It sounds like you just need to create and use a custom data template with the layouts and elements you want (pic, text etc.).